# How to open another website within the body of my website

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, iframe, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Rails 4 app.  I'd like for my user to be able to click on a button and open another random website within the page they are currently on.  The users could then navigate the new website and my page would maintain it's navigation bar and border around the new website.

How should I create this feature?

Comment: So you basically want to create a `proxy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, why don't you create an iframe and create a trigger (button in this case) to navigate that iframe. With Jquery it's simple:

Javascript (jQuery)

```
$("#button").click(function () { 
      $("#iframe").attr("src", "http://www.google.com/");
});
```

HTML:

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="" width="100%" height="400"></iframe><button id="button">Load</button>
```

try something like this. But make sure you load jQuery first :)

Comment: Since I did ask how to create a button feature that would open a page within a page, this answer is the most complete.  Adding a link to the iframe docs like @hexus did is also helpful

Answer (score 4):

I imagine that what you desire can be achieved with an `iframe`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

Answer (score 1):

**Proxy**

What you're referring to is known as a `proxy server` - quite common functionality on the net.

There are 100's of scripts to achieve this; the simplest is to use an [`iframe`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp):

> An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current
>   HTML document.

This will allow you to render other websites / web pages *within* your current webpage, maintaining your styling etc.

Comment: An `iframe` isn't actually a proxy; the client still makes the request to the embedded page.

Comment: Yes I know, sorrry - I meant it's what a lot of the proxies online actually do (similar functionality)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning a proxy server.  It was good to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a proxy. I would just put the first part but this has to be 30 characters so ima just keep going. Just create a Proxy cuh
.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).